# Split cofibrations up to quasi-isomorphism

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, model-categories, chain-complexes

$R$ a ring $(1\neq 0)$, $\mathbf{Perf}(R)$ is the category of perfect complexes (of right $R$-modules).

Suppose that $A_{\bullet}\rightarrow B_{\bullet}\rightarrow B_{\bullet}/A_{\bullet}$ a short exact sequence in $\mathbf{Perf}(R)$ such that

1. $A_{\bullet}\rightarrow B_{\bullet}$ is a cofibration in the projective model structure of chain complexes $\mathbf{Ch}_{R}$.
2. The homology of the chain complexes $A_{\bullet}$, $B_{\bullet}$ and $B_{\bullet}/A_{\bullet}$ is concentrated at level $n$ (the same $n$ for all $A_{\bullet}$, $B_{\bullet}$ and $B_{\bullet}/A_{\bullet}$ complexes).

Here is my question: Is it true that $A_{\bullet}\oplus B_{\bullet}/A_{\bullet} $ is isomorphic to $B_{\bullet}$ in homotopy category $Ho(\mathbf{Ch}_{R})$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You can construct counterexamples by taking projective resolutions of modules in a nonsplit short exact sequence. For example, from the short exact sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{2}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to0$ of abelian groups you get
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
&&0&&0&&0\\
&&@VVV&@VVV&@VVV\\
0@>>>0@>>>\mathbb{Z}@>\text{id}>>\mathbb{Z}@>>>0\\
&&@VVV&@VV\pmatrix{1\\2}V&@VV\times2V\\
0@>>>\mathbb{Z}@>>>\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}@>>>\mathbb{Z}@>>>0\\
&&@VVV&@VVV&@VVV\\
&&0&&0&&0\\
\end{CD}$$